# How to listen for a UDP broadcast when the default port could be already taken

Tags: c#, sockets

I am learning socket programming as I write a program that will essentially ping the network with it's credentials so that other instances of the same program can detect it.

Right now I have the port `49152` hard coded and I rarely run into issues but sometimes I end up getting the error which states that the port is in use.

Is there a way for all of my instances to discover each other on the network without listening for the broadcast on multiple ports at the same time?

Here is how I send the Pings to the network right now

```
public void Run() {
    Task.Run(() => {
        while (!Exit) {
            Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
            _pingSender.SendTo(serializedCredentials, //_pingSender is a socket
                new IPEndPoint(PortSettings.BroadCastAddress, PortSettings.BroadcastPorts[0]));
            Console.WriteLine($@"{Environment.NewLine}Sent {ListenerendPoint}");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question but you can check whether a port is already in use by using the code in this article https://softwarebydefault.com/2013/02/22/port-in-use/

Comment: That is only possible if the SO_REUSEPORT flag is set to true by the process binding that port first.

Comment: _"Is there a way for all of my instances to discover each other on the network without listening for the broadcast on multiple ports at the same time?"_ -- well, the obvious answer is to use a different port # than the one you already have some other program using. This is in fact the only real answer; IP is not intended for multiple processes to all be using the same port. It starts with the presumption that you are selecting unique ports for your servers (clients, of course, may use an OS-assigned port).