# How to change UDP broadcast port in the server if client's port is already occupied during server discovery?

Tags: java, android, udp, broadcast, service-discovery

I am trying to implement a server discovery between a PC (server) and an android phone, broadcasting a message from the server on a common port (8888).
I wonder what should I do if the port is already taken in the client, how can I change port on both, so that the client receives the broadcast message?
Should I use any specific network discovery protocol (UPnP or similar)?

Sorry if it is a basic question but I am not familiar with network programming. I will edit my question according to your observations.

I could only find this, but it has no answer:
[How to listen for a UDP broadcast when the default port could be already taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921280/how-to-listen-for-a-udp-broadcast-when-the-default-port-could-be-already-taken)

Comment: If you create a protocol, avoid using commonly used ports since the probability they are already used by another program is fairly high. You should create your own (between 0 and 65535 of course)

Comment: Yes, but what if that port is already used? If I distribute the applications to other persons, I can't change their ports manually..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, use an existing service discovery protocol like SSDP.  There is some prior work on this for Android you may be able to build from:  https://github.com/resourcepool/ssdp-client

The reasons to use SSDP:

- You're not going to run into any conflicts since the ports are properly reserved.
- It uses multicast rather than broadcast.  This may not matter much for you on your network, but IPv6 doesn't support broadcast, so it's already compatible.
- It's a standard protocol, so network administrators know what it is and can handle the traffic.

Comment: Thank you very much Brad! I read on Wikipedia that ssdp has been incorporated into UPnP, does it mean that UPnP is a step further? Do I need it?

Comment: Reading this: http://www.zeroconf.org/zeroconfandupnp.html I decided to go with Zeroconf, which in Android can be implemented using NSD: https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd